# Why is calling system grep slower than matching in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some code that loops through all the .rb files in a project and looks if they reference the `DateTime` class.  My first attempt looked like this:

```rb
file_names.each do |file_name|
  File.foreach(file_name) do |line|
    return file_name if line.match(/DateTime/)
  end
end
```

Benchmark results for the algorithm show that it takes about **0.6 seconds to run** through 1100 files, 25 times each. Not bad, but I had the thought that calling out to the system's `grep` command might be faster. My second attempt looks like this:

```rb
file_names.each do |file_name|
  return file_name if system("grep DateTime #{file_name} > /dev/null")
end
```

This takes **35.6 seconds** to run! Does anyone have any insight into why the second attempt performs so poorly? Is calling the system the slow part or is grep slower than the internal ruby code?

Comment: Your "first attempt" doesn't seem to contain the `file_names.each` loop. Besides, where are you `return`ing from, a method? How do you call it? And do both attempts yield the same results?

Comment: `grep` might be faster when working on multiple files, but the overhead of `system` is considerable when used in a loop.

Comment: Try using backticks to capture grep output from all files (e.g. put them in one command, not in a ruby loop)

Comment: Stefen, good catch.  I updated the code snippet. Both attempts do produce the same results (which is an array of file names that have DateTime inside them).  I tried to hide all the "other code" to keep the question simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is calling out to the system the slow partor is grep slower than the internal ruby code?

In your case, calling out to the system is slower. Particularly because of how you are **creating a new OS process for every single file**.

This means Ruby is having to ask the OS to create 1100 new sub-processes **(one at a time)**, and monitor those subprocesses for termination.

Since all the file IO in ruby is written in C under the hood (in mruby at least), it's going to be faster for your ruby script (which is already running it's own OS process and has allocated system memory), to open up files and search through them itself, rather than create 1100 sub-processes.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.